# VSTA in SSIS for SCR Task resize issue

Tags: ssis, vsta

When editing the a Script Task in a SSIS package (double click in the edit code of SCR) the **VSTA** env popups in an almost minimized window, I rememeber I resized it but now, even if I maximize the window and save it again, when I reopen it's the same small size. It's annoying.... Any idea when VS keep the latest values for VSTA so I can edit that?
Mario